# Why doesn't the markdown text appear on my posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

Im trying to create a post, but the text writen on markdown doesn't appear on it, this is what i have done:

- Post is placed on `_posts` and has a valid name `_posts/2018-01-01-firstPost.md`
- I've included a front matter and the layout html is rendered perfectly

`---
layout: post
published: true
---`

- I've tried to include `{{post.content}}`on my layout to see if the content of the post appeared without results.
- I've added `encoding: utf-8`to make sure it was encoded correctly.

Don't know what more to try any help will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Call your post content with `{{ content }}` from inside your template.

Any post data can be reached using `page` object (page.title, ...), not `post`.